# Call OnCheckedChanged event from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox

when user change the checkbox, I want first show my custom confirm dialog message. If user select yes, I want fire the code behing event processado_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

I tried something like:

`<asp:CheckBox ID="processado" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="javascript:confirmingChange();" AutoPostBack="true" />`

And my js:

```
function confirmingChange() {
     $.confirm({
        'title': 'Confirm',
        'message': 'Are you sure?',
        'buttons': {
            'Yes': {
               'action': function () {
                    __doPostBack(document.getElementById('processado'), '');
               }
            },
            'No': {
                'action': function () {
                     return false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

How can I fire my codebehind event using javascript?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need onchange instead of OnCheckedChanged and return true if you want postback and false otherwise.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="processado" runat="server" onchange="return javascript:confirmingChange();" 
      OnCheckedChanged="ServerSideEventHandlerHere" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

Comment: I did that, and changed the function to just return false, and anyway it will always execute the codebehind event alone. At the HTML, the event onchange is in <span> element and the other event is inside the <input> (which is inside of <span>)

Comment: I did not get you if you can get the generated html and make a fiddle ?

Comment: try binding the event using javascript and tell if it is triggered http://jsfiddle.net/2Encd/2/

Answer (score 3):

For calling javascript you have to use "**onchange**" and you have to use "**return**".

> onchange="return javascript:confirmingChange(); "

Comment: I did that, and changed the function to just return false, and anyway it will always execute the codebehind event alone. At the HTML, the event onchange is in <span> element and the other event is inside the <input> (which is inside of <span>)